# How to read CursorResult to Pandas in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

How does one convert a CursorResult-object into a Pandas Dataframe?

The following code results in a CursorResult-object:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{db_server}/{db_name}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={db_driver}")
q1 = "SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table"

with Session(engine) as session:
    results = session.execute(q1)
    session.commit()

type(results)
>sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult
```

As I couldn't find a way to extract relevant information from CursorResult, it attempted the following instead:

```
# Extracting data as we go
with Session(engine) as session:
    results = session.execute(q1)
    description = results.cursor.description
    rows = results.all()
    session.commit()

# Extracting column names
colnames = [elem[0] for elem in description]

# Extracting types
types = [elem[1] for elem in description]

# Creating dataframe
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=colnames)
```

But what about the dtypes? It doesn't work if I just put them in, though it looks like they are all python types. For my use case I MUST use **Session**, so I cannot use the first suggestion of doing the classic:

```
# I cannot use
pandas.read_sql(q1, engine)
```

The reason for this is that I have to do multi-batch queries within the same context, which is why I am using the **Session** class.

Comment: You must manually map SQLAlchemy types to Pandas dtypes. I don't think Pandas exposes that kind of information in the public API. That said, you can definitely batch queries together into transactions using the "core" API. Or are you trying to interleave ORM object insertions with reading data into Pandas?

Comment: As pd.read_sql() reads the types from SQLAlchemy, then shouldn't there be a way to do it too with if I have a list of types?

Comment: For basic data types, it should "just work" as in Corralien's answer. But if you want to do anything specific related to number data types, arrays, etc. you might have to do a bit of post-processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, just use `pd.DataFrame` constructor. `dtypes` are correctly set.

```
# sqlalchemy==2.0.16
# pandas==2.0.2
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

with Session(engine) as session:
    results = session.execute(text(q1))
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    # session.commit()  # commit is irrelevant if you don't write data
```

Test on my database:

```
>>> df.head()
                    Scenario Attribute      Process  Period Region Vintage            PV
0  WithHHP16HinsHE0CCS109LHP   VAR_Cap  EVTRANS_H-L    2014     FR    None    296.071141
1  WithHHP16HinsHE0CCS109LHP   VAR_Cap  EVTRANS_H-M    2014     FR    None     11.770909
2  WithHHP16HinsHE0CCS109LHP   VAR_Cap   IMPELCHIGA    2014     FR    None  11851.674497
3  WithHHP16HinsHE0CCS109LHP   VAR_Cap  EVTRANS_H-L    2015     FR    None    296.071141
4  WithHHP16HinsHE0CCS109LHP   VAR_Cap  EVTRANS_H-M    2015     FR    None     11.770909

>>> df.dtypes
Scenario      object
Attribute     object
Process       object
Period         int64
Region        object
Vintage       object
PV           float64
dtype: object
```

**Edit**:

```
rec = results.fetchone()

>>> rec
('WithHHP16HinsHE0CCS109LHP', 'VAR_Cap', 'EVTRANS_H-L', 2014, 'FR', None, 296.071141357762)
#                                           python int  --^       python float --^

>>> type(rec)
sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row
```

Comment: But does this approach just "guess" the types rather than translate the SQL types into pandas types? E.g. why are "Scenario" not read as strings?

Comment: No the constructor doesn't try to cast the values. It's because the cursor has the right type. If you do `pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['1', '2', '3']})` the `ColA` will not be cast to `int`, it remains `object` (because it's a string).

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt "scenario" is not read as a string because Pandas uses `object` for string data by default, for backward-compatibility. You usually will want to convert string columns to `pd.StringDtype()`, but it's not the default yet because it uses a completely different (not Numpy) array backend that's considered somewhat experimental still.

Comment: But there must be some translation of types somewhere, right? E.g. if the type is varchar(255), then pandas should probably translate it to a string, or if the SQL type is int, then it must be translated to e.g. int64.

Comment: pandas keeps surprising with its types. Polars, Pytorch etc. are seem to have much more consistent types. The "object" just seems lazy.

Comment: Yes you are right but a number still remain numeric and other data will be object.